# Apache beam python groupbykey with kafka io streaming data

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-beam, windowing

I'm trying to create fixed windows of 10 sec using apache beam 2.23 with kafka as data source.
It seems to be getting triggered for every record even if I try to set AfterProcessingtime trigger to 15 and throwing the following error if I try to use GroupByKey.
Error : KeyError: 0 [while running '[17]: FixedWindow']

**Data simulation :**

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time
producer = KafkaProducer()
id_val = 1001
while(1):
    message = {}
    message['id_val'] = str(id_val)
    message['sensor_1'] = 10
    if (id_val<1003):
        id_val = id_val+1
    else:
        id_val=1001
    time.sleep(2)
    print(time.time())
    producer.send('test', str(message).encode())
```

**Beam snippet :**

```
class AddTimestampFn(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, element):
    timestamp = int(time.time())
    yield beam.window.TimestampedValue(element, timestamp)



pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
lines = p | "Reading messages from Kafka" >> kafkaio.KafkaConsume(kafka_config)
groups = (
    lines
    | 'ParseEventFn' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (ast.literal_eval(x[1])))
    | 'Add timestamp' >> beam.ParDo(AddTimestampFn())
    | 'After timestamp add ' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn("timestamp add"))
    | 'FixedWindow' >> beam.WindowInto(
        beam.window.FixedWindows(10*1),allowed_lateness = 30)
    | 'Group ' >> beam.GroupByKey())
    | 'After group' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn("after group")))
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have just started using beam so it could be something really silly.

Comment: I'm sitting with the same problem, are you using kafkaio.KafkaConsume as a library from BEAM or is it defined by you?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?